# solr commit returns 400 bad request , In Log :- Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'

Tags: tomcat, solr, console-application, solrnet

i am New to solr and i am trying to make 1 sample test application, when application execute 
and i get error in visual studio on run time, error :--solr commit returns 400 bad request

and in solr log file i got error :-- Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'

Why this error ..

apache tomcat solr version :- 4.6.0

solrnet.dll version :- 0.3.0.0

Solr code in .net application:-

```
var files = new TextFileRepository(this.connectionString).GetTextFiles();
solrWorker.Add(files);
solrWorker.Commit(); --> here i get errro "solr commit returns 400 bad request"
```

How to resolve it..?

regards..

Comment: are you sure you solrnet.dll is compatible with solr 4.6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an older version of SolrNet. This error is a known issue with older versions of SolrNet and Solr 4.X. Please grab an updated version from one of the following:

- [NuGet - Pre-Release v0.4.0-beta2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SolrNet/0.4.0-beta2)
- [Solr Nightly Builds](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1) - (click the Artifacts link to get access to the downloadable zip)
- [GitHub Source](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/) - pull the latest source down and compile locally or use a [release](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/releases).

Comment: See FrKunze reply below: **NuGet -Pre is currently NOT working for Solr 4!**

Comment: @Laoujin Please see https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md#downloads , that'll always be the authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, in addition to Paige Cook's answer, that currently (Jan 2015) NuGet doesn't hold the latest version. Using `Install-Package SolrNet -Pre` you get an assembly with version number `0.4.0.2002`, which is the current number, but there is a more recent version within this version number (tricky!). To fix the problem, use [GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/) or [SolrNightlyBuilds](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=SolrNet) instead.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md#downloads , that'll always be the authoritative source.